# android Mvp pattern passing context as view

Tags: android, mvp

I have tried to pass Mainactivity as view to presenter

```
(In MainActivity)    
mainPresenter = new MainPresenter(this);

(Presenter cont)
public MainPresenter(View view) {
      this.view = view;
      user  = new User();
   }
```

However, this throw error which is invalid casting or something. 
Am I missing something?

That code is from [here](http://thefinestartist.com/android/mvp-pattern)

Comment: Are you implementing `MainPresenter.View` in MainActivity?

Comment: Do I need to create that ? or its built in interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have something like that :

```
public interface YourView {
    void doSomething();
}

public MainActivity extends Activity implements YourView {

mainPresenter = new MainPresenter(this);

}

public MainPresenter(YourView view) {
      this.view = view;
      view.doSomething();
   }
```